# Dyno is not enabled

Tags: python, heroku, python-telegram-bot

am trying to build a telegram bot on heroku. The bot works fine on my local testing, when I published it to heroku for some reason the dyno is not working. I checked if there any problem in my program bot nothing.

even tried to launch it manually to see if there is any missing package or errors:

```
heroku run bash -a app1
python bot.py
```

and the application started normally without any problem.

also tried to restart dynos but nothing happened the dyno is still **OFF**.

Procfile

```
worker: python bot.py
```

PS:

- am using the free plan
- tried to see the logs but it didn't show any error

```
2021-10-20T14:59:56.732258+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 348270fc by user *@gmail.com

2021-10-20T14:59:56.732258+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user *@gmail.com

2021-10-20T15:00:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded**
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after reading heroku documentation on Dynos, because this is a `worker` dyno not a `web` dyno you need to rescale it to 1.

```
PS> heroku scale worker=1
Scaling dynos... done, now running worker at 1:Free
```

Everything should work fine from there.

**Reference:**

[Dynos and the Dyno Manager](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos)

[Dyno Types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types)